# unable to call a get SnapShot function in vb.net. Would appreciate any h-e-l-p

Tags: vb.net

I hope my question is good enough. Some people said they're not sometimes. :) I have my SnapShot function but I'm unable to call it. Compiler says: function is not declared or my be unaccessible due to its protection level... here's my function...

```
   Private Function getShapshot(ByVal strModule As String) As Integer

        Dim strName As String = Empty.ToString

        Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(strName)
        Dim hSnapshot As IntPtr = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(&H10, CUInt(p(0).Id))
        If hSnapshot = IntPtr.Zero Then Return Nothing
        Dim me32Modules As New MODULEENTRY32
        me32Modules.U32Size = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(me32Modules))
        If Module32First(hSnapshot, me32Modules) Then
            Do
                If strModule = (me32Modules.U32Size) Then Return me32Modules.HModule
            Loop While (Module32Next(hSnapshot, me32Modules))
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

It might be my function call: Its `getShapshot(strName)` where `strName` is process name.   So I guess I need some help. And it will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you calling it from a different class? if so, remove the "Private" keyword on the method declaration.

Comment: No, I'm not calling it from another class. I tried making the function public, but that didn't work. Thanks for the help though. Also, thanks for fixing my post (I'm guessing you did). I couldn't get the first line of code in the code block.

Comment: Show us the class that contains the method doing the calling and the method being called.

Comment: I had to put the code in an answer because a comment doesn't allow enough room for the code...

Answer (score 0):

```
`Private Class myProcessEx
    'inner enum used only internally
    <Flags>
    Private Enum SnapshotFlags As UInteger
        HeapList = &H1
        Process = &H2
        Thread = &H4
        [Module] = &H8
        Module32 = &H10
        Inherit = &H80000000UI
        All = &H1F            NoHeaps = &H40000000
    End Enum
    'inner struct used only internally
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Structure PROCESSENTRY32
        Const MAX_PATH As Integer = 260
        Friend dwSize As UInt32
        Friend cntUsage As UInt32
        Friend th32ProcessID As UInt32
        Friend th32DefaultHeapID As IntPtr
        Friend th32ModuleID As UInt32
        Friend cntThreads As UInt32
        Friend th32ParentProcessID As UInt32
        Friend pcPriClassBase As Int32
        Friend dwFlags As UInt32
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=MAX_PATH)>
        Friend szExeFile As String
    End Structure
    Declare Function Module32First Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, lppe As MODULEENTRY32) As Long
    Private Declare Function Module32Next Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hSnapShot As Long, ByVal lpMe32 As MODULEENTRY32) As Long


    <DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
    Shared Function CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(<[In]> dwFlags As UInt32, <[In]> th32ProcessID As UInt32) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Public Function getShapshot(ByVal strModule As String) As Integer

        Dim strName As String = Empty.ToString

        Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(strName)
        Dim hSnapshot As IntPtr = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(&H10, CUInt(p(0).Id))
        If hSnapshot = IntPtr.Zero Then Return Nothing
        Dim me32Modules As New MODULEENTRY32
        me32Modules.U32Size = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(me32Modules))
        If Module32First(hSnapshot, me32Modules) Then
            Do
                If strModule = (me32Modules.U32Size) Then Return me32Modules.HModule
            Loop While (Module32Next(hSnapshot, me32Modules))
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class`   This is the class code, next comes the calling function... ` Private Function getShapshot(ByVal strModule As String) As Integer

        Dim strName As String = Empty.ToString

        Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(strName)
        Dim hSnapshot As IntPtr = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(&H10, CUInt(p(0).Id))
        If hSnapshot = IntPtr.Zero Then Return Nothing
        Dim me32Modules As New MODULEENTRY32
        me32Modules.U32Size = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(me32Modules))
        If Module32First(hSnapshot, me32Modules) Then
            Do
                If strModule = (me32Modules.U32Size) Then Return me32Modules.HModule
            Loop While (Module32Next(hSnapshot, me32Modules))
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class` calling code..                                        `Private Function getShapshot(ByVal strModule As String) As Integer

        Dim strName As String = Empty.ToString

        Dim p() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(strName)
        Dim hSnapshot As IntPtr = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(&H10, CUInt(p(0).Id))
        If hSnapshot = IntPtr.Zero Then Return Nothing
        Dim me32Modules As New MODULEENTRY32
        me32Modules.U32Size = CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(me32Modules))
        If Module32First(hSnapshot, me32Modules) Then
            Do
                If strModule = (me32Modules.U32Size) Then Return me32Modules.HModule
            Loop While (Module32Next(hSnapshot, me32Modules))
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class` this should give you a better idea of what is going on.
```

Comment: I found a fix for the issue. I put all the code in a module and now it works. Thanks for the help guys. I really appreciate it.

Comment: use the back quotes only around in-line code. for formatting the rest just put everything on a new line and indent 4.

Comment: Also, please don't just bung everything in modules... it just makes everything global and is not exactly good OOP practice. It's better to solve your actual problem. I'm still looking at your code here and you've got 3 (almost) identical `getShapshot` functions (one public and two private) and we *still* can't see where it is called from. Your class is also private, so are you saying that you made the class a module? Did you try just making that public first?

Comment: @monty I apologize. I did not see your last 2 comments. Thanks for the tip about adding code. Also, you're right about cramming things in a module. Not good practice. I guess I always looked at Modules as a toolbox for other projects. Thanks for all the help...

Comment: that's what dll's are for :)